# android retrofit picasso how to load images from node.js folder

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

i have implemented a recyclerview of Bike objects with dynamic content (except the image)
and it works fine , but now i have decided to make my images dynamic and display them with my objects in the recyclerview , i saw tutorials about picasso but i did not understand anything , i have an image property inside the Bike object , and this property contains "http://localhost:3000/images/bike.png" for example, how to load my bike with it's images using retrofit and picasso , i will show what i have tried but clearly the syntax of picasso is error in BikeAdapter.

//BikeAdapter:

```
package com.example.miniprojetandroid.adapters;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.R;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Bike;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;


public class BikesAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<Bike> bikes;
    private Context mContext;
    private Callback mCallback;

public BikesAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        this.mContext = mContext ;
        this.bikes = bikes;
        }

@NonNull
@Override
public BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.bike_list_item, parent, false);
        return new BikesViewHolder(mItemView, this);
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Bike singleItem = bikes.get(position);

        holder.BikeName.setText(singleItem.getModel());
        holder.BikeImage.setBackgroundResource(singleItem.getImage());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://localhost:3000/images/bike.png").placeholder( ?).into(holder.BikeImage);
        holder.bikeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallback.onItemClicked(singleItem);
            }
        });
        holder.BikeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,singleItem.getModel(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
        }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return bikes.size();
        }

public class BikesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final TextView BikeName;
    public final ImageView BikeImage;
    public final Button bikeView;
    final BikesAdapter mAdapter;

    public BikesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, BikesAdapter mAdapter) {
        super(itemView);
        this.BikeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikeName);
        this.BikeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikeImage);
        this.bikeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_view);
        this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
    }
}


    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onItemClicked(Bike bike);
    }

}
```

My Fragment that contains the recyclerview

```
package com.example.miniprojetandroid.ui.fragments;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.BikeService;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.RetrofitClient;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.UserService;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.adapters.BikesAdapter;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Bike;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.User;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import com.squareup.picasso.*;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements BikesAdapter.Callback{

    private BikeService apiService;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();
    private  BikesAdapter mAdapter;
    List<Bike> result = new ArrayList<Bike>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container,false);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_bikes);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        apiService = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(BikeService.class);
        mAdapter = new BikesAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList<Bike>) bikes);
        fillData();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setCallback(this);
        return rootView;

    }


    public void fillData(){

        Call<List<Bike>> call = apiService.getBikes();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Bike>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Bike>> call, Response<List<Bike>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    bikes.addAll(response.body());
                    for(Bike bike: bikes){
                        bike.setImage(R.drawable.ruebike);
                    }
                    Log.e("Bike LIST", bikes.toString());
                      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Bike>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        /*bikes.add(new Bike(1,"ECO", "RTT" , "44", R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(2,"AAA", "RTT" , "33",  R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(3,"BBB", "RUE" , "11",  R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(4,"EEE", "SPORT" , "25",  R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(5,"CCC", "SPORT" , "77", R.drawable.ruebike ));
        Log.e("USERS LIST", bikes.toString());*/

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(Bike bike) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("bike_id",bike.getId());
        bundle.putString("model", bike.getModel());
        bundle.putString("type", bike.getType());
        bundle.putString("price", bike.getPrice());
        bundle.putInt("image", bike.getImage());
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();
        f.setArguments(bundle);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentsContainer, f )
                .commit();
    }

}
```

I believe that my hole problem is in that method in BikeAdapter

```
@NonNull
@Override
public BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.bike_list_item, parent, false);
        return new BikesViewHolder(mItemView, this);
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Bike singleItem = bikes.get(position);

        holder.BikeName.setText(singleItem.getModel());
        holder.BikeImage.setBackgroundResource(singleItem.getImage());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://localhost:3000/images/bike.png").placeholder( ?).into(holder.BikeImage);
        holder.bikeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallback.onItemClicked(singleItem);
            }
        });
        holder.BikeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,singleItem.getModel(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
        }
```

and exactly at this line :

holder.BikeImage.setBackgroundResource(singleItem.getImage());
Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://localhost:3000/images/bike.png").placeholder( ?).into(holder.BikeImage);

how to load my image ??? what to correct in picasso syntax?

//my bike model

```
package com.example.miniprojetandroid.models;


import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.Ignore;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Entity(tableName = "bike_table")
public class Bike {

    @SerializedName("bike_id")
    @Expose
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    @SerializedName("model")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "model")
    public String model;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    public String  type;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    public String price;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image")
    public int image;


    @Ignore
    public Bike(){
    }

    @Ignore
    public Bike( String model, int image) {
        this.model = model;
        this.image = image;
    }


    public Bike( String model, String type, String price, int image) {
        this.model = model;
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Ignore
    public Bike(int id, String model, String price, String type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.model = model;
        this.price = price;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Ignore
    public Bike(int id, String model, String type, String price,  int image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.model = model;
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bike{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", model='" + model + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", price='" + price + '\'' +
                ", image=" + image +
                '}';
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get rid of this.

```
holder.BikeImage.setBackgroundResource(singleItem.getImage());
```

and use this

```
Picasso.get().load(singleItem.getImage()).into(holder.BikeImage);
```